# How to parse array data using Volley (TextView)

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-volley

```
package com.sp.demoapiheader;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mTextViewResult;
    private RequestQueue mQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
        Button buttonParse = findViewById(R.id.button_parse);

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/BusServices", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (!response.equals(null)) {
                    Log.e("Your Array Response", response);

                } else {
                    Log.e("Your Array Response", "Data Null");
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("error is ", "" + error);
            }
        }) {

            //This is for Headers If You Needed
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                params.put("AccountKey", "XXXX==");
                return params;
            }

            //Pass Your Parameters here
            /*@Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("User", UserName);
                params.put("Pass", PassWord);
                return params;
            }*/
        };
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(request);

    }
}
```

I would like to parse the data into a textview and display each variable in a string/int format. As can be seen in the code, there's an simple XML file with a button and textview. Do i implement JSONArray or JSONObject at some point into the code? Currently, the code only allows a response in the run tab.

Comment: did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626934/how-to-parse-json-array-in-android-using-volley

Comment: @ManikandanK, Hi sir, yes i'm able to get my string data response to show in the run view, but what i would like to achieve is to get it show on a TextView instead

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve json array parser for two ways to shows in textview

1) Gson convertor dependency

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}


@Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body());
        List<MenuResponseModel> listArr = new ArrayList<>();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            try {               
                MenuResponseModel menuResponseModel = gson.fromJson(response.body().string(), MenuResponseModel.class);
                if (menuResponseModel.getStaus().equals("1")) {
                    listArr.addAll(menuResponseModel.getData());                        
                 for (int i = 0; i < listArr.size(); i++) {

                    Integer price = Integer.parseInt(foodOrderList.get(i).getFood_quantity()) * Integer.parseInt(foodOrderList.get(i).getFood_price());
                    stringBuffer.append("\n\nFood Name: " + foodOrderList.get(i).getFood_name() + "\n Food Quantity : " + foodOrderList.get(i).getFood_quantity() + "\n Food Price :" + price.toString());
                tv_order_details.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
            }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

2) JSONArray classs

```
try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject js = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    stringBuffer.append("Name :"+js.getString("customer_name")+" - Table No: "+js.getString("table_id")+js.getString("seats"));
                }   mTextViewResult.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```